# Java Best way to extract parts from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string;

```
[Username [rank] -> me] message
```

The characters of the rank, username, and message will vary each time. What is the best way I can break this into three separate variables (Username, rank and message)?

I have experimented with:

```
String[] parts = text.split("] ");
```

But it is throwing back errors. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what characters can and cannot appear as delimiters?  Will all strings have this exact sequence of symbols as delimiters?

Comment: Any characters can in the message, but the username and rank is only alphanumerical. All variables will vary in length. I thought if you could trim the username and rank, you would then be left with the message.

Comment: What about the symbols that surround those strings?  What can the be?  (That's what I mean by delimiters.)

Comment: Like the brackets and the arrow? That will always be the same no matter what.

Comment: What errors is it giving you?

Comment: I am getting "Unclosed character class" pointing at "[" in "String[] parts = text.split("[");"

Comment: @user3794577 `split()` takes regex, so use `split("\\[")`

Comment: Even if you wouldn't get errors with your code – you'll quickly see that it is extremely unpractical, resulting in over-bloated, complex, unflexible code. You're best off with regexes for such problems.

Comment: Thanks, now that I am no longer getting errors I have fixed the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Java's support for regular expressions (`java.util.regex`) and let a regex match the 3 parts.

For example this one: `^\[([\w]+) \[([\w]+)\] -> \w+\] (.*)$`

Java code snippet, slightly adapted from Ian F. Darwin's "Java Cookbook" (O'Reilly):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String pat = "^\\[([\\w]+) \\[([\\w]+)\\] -> \\w+\\] (.*)$";
        Pattern rx = Pattern.compile(pat);
        String text = "[Username [rank] -> me] message";
        Matcher m = rx.matcher(text);
        if(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Match found:");
            for(int i=0; i<=m.groupCount(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println("  Group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match found:
  Group 0: [Username [rank] -> me] message
  Group 1: Username
  Group 2: rank
  Group 3: message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "[whatever [Is] -> me] Input";
String user, rank, message;

user = input.substring(1, input.indexOf('[', 1));
rank = input.substring(input.indexOf('[', 1), input.indexOf(']'));
message = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(']'));
```

this should work but if you really want it done right you should make a separate object that holds all this and can output it as a string. depends where this is coming from and where its going.
-axon

Comment: Make the format of the line that needs to be parsed a bit more complex and you'll quickly end up with extremely complex and unflexible code. And you'll have a problem with the last line of your code if the actual message contains a ] character.